# SSD instead of DVD temperature

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, temperature

just installed Intel 320 instead of DVD in Macbook MC516LL.
Does old DVD place is equivalent to standard HDD place in Macbook from temperature (thermal) perspective?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying this a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the SSD is likely to be powered on much more than the DVD ever was, your thermal load inside the mac will be higher. Most SSD use even more power at idle than HDD, but it won't be nearly as bad as the CPU/GPU running full tilt. The fans may run faster to compensate if the ambient temperature is high, but I've heard no hints of problems even from people in warm environments with SSD+HDD.

There are many apps to log the temperatures so you can get a before / after log and check on things as you should whenever you add parts not planned by the manufacturer.

Comment: My question was more about SSD health. I afraid that CPU neighborhood potentially can increase SSD degradation.

Comment: Still shouldn't be an issue. You have the means to make your own measurements and check against the manufacturer specs. The airflow in MacBook is such that the battery / optical / HDD bays are the coolest and the CPU heat goes back and up past the display - not forward in the case.

Answer (score 2):

SSD Should be safe. I have the same scenario - my drive is a WD Caviar Black 500GB runing at 7200 rpm (WD500BEKT) and I have a Intel 320 120GB SSD on the optical drive. I have a 13" MBP 2010, which has a little better motherboard layout, but the same chipset. Here is my point:

- Intel 320 does not have a thermal sensor.
- Intel 320 has 5 years of warranty.
- The drive's operating temperature range is 0˚C to 70˚C ([Intel 320 Specs](http://download.intel.com/design/flash/nand/325152.pdf))
- The only wear out indicator is the E9 Smart attribute ([media wear-out indicator](http://www.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/CS-032510.htm)), and it's not connected to the temperature at all.
- You always have a backup, right?

Having all this in mind: There should be very hard to reach 70˚C inside the drive bay and EVEN if your device fails because of that, there is no way for Intel to prove this (there is not a temperature record in the SMART database).